# IterationSafetyFactor error in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, implicit

I am solving a set of 4 coupled, nonlinear ODEs using ImplicitRungeKutta in NDSolve. I am running the solutions over many different initial conditions, and for about 20% of solutions, I get the error *NDSolve::impsitsf: Unable to satisfy the ImplicitSolver tolerance for IterationSafetyFactor at t = 3126.5435073757453`*. The time changes depending on the solution.

I don't know what this error means or how to fix it. The documentation for IterationSafetyFactor wasn't helpful, and the solutions that yield this error don't look any different.

```
gammap[px_, py_] := (1 + px^2 + py^2)^0.5;
odepx[py_, fx_, gammap_, ex_,  bz_] := (fx == -(ex + py*bz/gammap));
odepy[px_, fy_, gammap_, ey_, bz_] := (fy == -(ey - px*bz/gammap));
odex[vx_, px_, gammap_] := (vx == px/gammap);
odey[vy_, py_, gammap_] := (vy == py/gammap);
powerp[px_, py_, fx_, fy_, gamma_] := (2/3) ((fx^2*px^2 + fy^2*py^2) + 
  gamma^2*(fx^2*py^2 + fy^2*px^2))/(px^2 + py^2);

sol[init_, tfinal_] := 
  NDSolve[{odex[ x'[t], px[t], gammap[px[t], py[t]]],
    odey[ y'[t], py[t], gammap[px[t], py[t]]] , 
    odepx[py[t], px'[t], gammap[px[t], py[t]], Ex[x[t], y[t]] , 
     Bz[x[t], y[t]]],
    odepy[px[t], py'[t], gammap[px[t], py[t]], Ey[x[t], y[t]], 
     Bz[x[t], y[t]]], 
    {x[0], y[0], px[0], py[0]} == init},
   {x, y, px, py}, {t, 0, tfinal}, Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta"}];
model = Association[{}];
Do[model[{250., 2000, 600 + j 200./9}] = 
   sol[{0, 250., 2000, 600 + j 200./9}, 10^4];
  Print[StringTemplate["run 1 solution `1` completed"][j]], {j,0,9}];
```

Running this code requires the fields Bz, Ey, and Ex, which are large (~50MB) interpolating functions. I don't quite know how to attach files, so here's [a link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fOmqrO8LGS5tsUCkkKJvt23pJ05KHB6D?usp=sharing). Any help would be appreciated.

Update - using the method noted in the comments, the error disappears!

```
Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", AccuracyGoal 
-> MachinePrecision, PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
"IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}
```

I'm still not sure what the error means, however.

Comment: I get an extrapolation warning for `j == 0, 1, 2` (`InterpolatingFunction::dmval`).  That would worry me at least as much as a warning the solver failed to get a sufficiently accurate solution.  The failure of the implicit solver could be due to a lack of smoothness in the interpolating functions.  [This tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveImplicitRungeKutta.html) uses the settings ``Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision, PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision, "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}``.

Comment: Michael E2 - Changing the method eliminated the error, thanks! Regarding the extrapolation error, that is expected. I only care about the solution in a domain where I've specified Bz, Ey, and Ex, so once the solution leaves that domain (and the warning is triggered) I disregard it. Additionally, I've let those functions go to 0 at the edge of the domain, so they extrapolate to 0 outside it to avoid any weird behavior.